# Record audio on facebook

Tags: facebook, audio, web, record

I would like to create an app on a fan page that allows a facebook user to record audio using their mic. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. it is possible - start here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/feed-gaming/  then learn how to use Flash to read webcam and mic data